# What is draw the structure of php application?

Tags: php, uml

I have been asked to make a php application. There is a part in the requirements that says

> draw the structure of application and
>   scripting as well.

What does it mean? I have already done the script. Does it mean that I have to make a diagram of it, like DB diagram in dia or in some other software?

If it is like UML design then please check this website: http://www.websequencediagrams.com/

for which I have entered the description like this:

> WebBrowser->Server: Input
>   Server->PHP: Request
>   PHP->Processing: Action
>   Processing->To Server: Process DB   To
>   Server->To Browser: Output

Also, what do you think that what should be the description of following in order to make the UML diagram on above said website:

1. The application needs to import contacts from CSV file or TXT file.
2. While importing the contacts, the application should remove duplicates
3. There will be two type of contacts, email,and the Phone Number. The application should sense the contact type and differentiate.
4. The application should be able to send bulk emails to all contacts in the list.
5. The application should log number of emails sent to certain user i.e. (if first we get 10 emails addresses in list and send them 2 emails and afterwards add 34 new email addresses and and then send 3 emails, there should be a log of which user received how many emails from our app).

Please help me out.

Comment: Are you unable to ask the client/employer for clarification? I think this is a good question, and it'd be interesting to see some details about how others diagram their applications, but if you want to know what it means in the requirement, then only the author can tell you that.

Answer (score 4):

By draw the structure, I think they're referring to a flow chart or uml diagram illustrating how the application will function (class diagram).

They probably want a database relational diagram as well.

That's just what I think, based on what you wrote.

Comment: +1 just for reading the wall of text without developing eye problems.

Comment: And yet the witty comment gets more upvotes than the answer itself :P
[edit]
And it changed like 1 minute after my comment. Duh.